# How can I set a default value using SELECT2 input box method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a dynamic form that has multiple dropdowns. Each dropdown is composed of officers name. My problem is I don't know how to set a default value.
In the update form I simply used a standard dropdown and from there I can set the initial value but I want to use select2 for standard dropdown in all of my forms.

Here's my code:

```
<!-- OLD DROPDOWN WORKS FINE -->
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="contract_main_jp_officer[]">
    <?php if($v['main_jp'] == 0) { ?>
        <option value=""> -- SELECT OFFICER --</option>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php select_officer($v['main_jp']); ?>
</select>

<!-- I USED SELECT2 DROPDOWN -->
<input type="text" class="form-control officer_selection input-sm form_control_outline input_white upper off_sel" name="contract_main_jp_officer[]" value="<?php echo set_value('contract_main_jp_officer', 0); ?>" />
<label for="name" class="text-info">Main Japanese Relation Officer: </label>
```

Here's the helper to get my saved value (but it is for normal dropdown):

```
if ( ! function_exists('select_officer')) {
    function select_officer($selected = 0) {

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->model('contracts/Contracts_model');

        $officer = $CI->Contracts_model->load_relation_officer();
        $row_list = array();

        foreach($officer as $l) {

            $s = ($selected == $l['id']) ? "selected='selected'" : "";
            echo "<option value='" . $l['id'] . "' " . $s . ">" . $l['text'] . "</option>";

        }

    }
}
```

And in my page load I initialize this part so that I can get all the values I needed to put in the dropdowns.

```
//officer lists
$(".officer_selection").select2({
    data: data
});
```

Can you help me how can I set a default value in a multiple dropdowns?
I have 4 kinds of dropdowns these are the Main Japanese Officer, Assistant Japanese Officer, Main Local Officer and Assistant Local Officer. All of them contains same dropdown values.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.officer_selection').each(function(){
$(this).find('option:eq(3)').prop('selected', true);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select class= 'officer_selection'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>


<select class= 'officer_selection'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo1</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab1</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes1</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi1</option>
</select>

<select class= 'officer_selection'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo2</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab2</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes2</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi2</option>
</select>


<select class= 'officer_selection'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo3</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab3</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes3</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input type="text" id="select2-sample">
```

Initialize select 2 with data

```
$("#select2-sample").select2(
    {
      data:{results:[{name:"item1", id:123},{name:"item2", id:456}], text:"name"},
      formatSelection: function(item){return ashtmlString(item.name);},
      formatResult: function(item){return item.name}
    }
);
```

Set a default value

```
$("#select2-sample").select2('val', 456);
```

Comment: Ok, ill try it. :)